# Chart X Axis wrong labels

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

I have a chart and a datagridview, both of them are databound to a dictionary, for example:

```
freqChart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(symCount.Keys, symCount.Values);
```

And on the screenshot below you can see the difference in X-Axis label/key names. Datagridview shows it correctly, while chart flips char if it's punctuation char. What's the problem? How do I fix it?

Screenshot (Chart and DataGridView):

[image]

Comment: What characters do you have exactly? Can you post them as text?

Comment: "E,H", ",HZ", "'GS", "ZE,", "WB'" - like this?

Comment: Ok, and how do you bind the dictionary to the dgv? Nothing like you show happens here. Hard to imagine what could be the cause, not even right-to-left would do that. Nor any Label.LabelStyle.Format I can think of Try the debugger to look into the values.

Comment: foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in symCount3)
     symDgv3.Rows.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
Debugger shows the same key names, as they should have been, nothing changes after databind. Also, to confirm that nothing happens to dictionary, chart gets the data first, then datagridview, it would be strange if something has changed in dictionary

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this behavior with the code that you posted here. The problem appears to be somewhere else. Please, create [a complete, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment was wrong; in fact this is a funny effect you get when you have a [**`RightToLeft`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft(v=vs.110).aspx) turned on.

There are several values but this one is enough to reproduce:

```
freqChart.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes
```

Either this is what you want, then you can turn it on for the DGV as well; or it isn't then simply turn it off..

```
freqChart.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No
```

As you can see it is a Control.Property so it will work on all controls. Also to be noted: The RightToLeft property is an ambient property, so it propagates to child controls.

Why it acts so strangly I can't say, though. The docs basically talk about alignment, not punctuation. If you are interested you may want to read up on it in  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text)

Comment: +1, that's why OP should have posted an MCVE. As to the reason: punctuation marks are used in right-to-left systems and, thus, support some level of [bi-directionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text) (e.g. [comma](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002c/index.htm)). Latin letters, OTOH, are explicitly left-to-right, so they don't change positions.

Comment: Intersting link! According to it it is the other way round: Punctuation characters are 'neutral' so the don't move.  Most alphabetic characters are 'strong' characters, i.e. characters  with definite directionality. - Oh, well, even if OP wanted it, this seems a mine-field.. When the punct.char is in the middle, nothing is changing..